# Concate list of vectors in q

Tags: kdb

I have the following two lists:

```
x:(("AA";"AA");("BB";"BB"))
y:(("11";"11");("22";"22"))
```

I am targeting this result:

z = (("AA11";"AA11");("BB22";"BB22"))

I have tried:

```
x,'y
```

but this results in all the vectors joined not by sub vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the lists are nested, you need to use `each-both` twice :

```
q)x,''y
(("AA11";"AA11");("BB22";"BB22"))
```

Or if you don't care about the structure, you can first `raze` it and use single `each-both`

```
q)raze[x],'raze[y]
("AA11";"AA11";"BB22";"BB22")
```

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution using `.z.s` and `each-both` when you are not sure of nested levels:

```
q)f:{$[10h=type x;x,y;.z.s'[x;y]]}

q)x:(("AA";"AA");("BB";"BB"))
q)y:(("11";"11");("22";"22"))

q)f[x;y]
(("AA11";"AA11");("BB22";"BB22"))


q)x:((("AA";"AA");("BB";"BB"));(("CC";"CC");("DD";"DD")))
q)y:((("11";"11");("22";"22"));(("33";"33");("44";"44")))

q)f[x;y]
((("AA11";"AA11");("BB22";"BB22"));(("CC33";"CC33");("DD44";"DD44")))
```